# how to solve this problem ? "You don't have permission to edit anything. " in django

Tags: django

i created a superuser account , but when I log in with it , i can't edit any of the installed applications !

how can I grant permissions for this user to allow editing applications ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django. You don't have permission to edit anything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718077/django-you-dont-have-permission-to-edit-anything)

Comment: Which version of Django do you use?

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the line admin.autodiscover() to your main urls.py, making sure to do from django.contrib import admin first.

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929707/django-admin-not-seeing-any-app-permission-problem/1930130#1930130)

Answer (score 3):

Found this info [useful](https://github.com/jsocol/django-adminplus/issues/17#issuecomment-53384607) in this context.

So simply replace django.contrib.admin with django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig in installed apps.

```
from adminplus.sites import AdminSitePlus

#Add this line.  
admin.site = AdminSitePlus()
admin.autodiscover()  # automatic autodiscover should be turned off in settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you created `admin.py` files for all your apps, registered the models, and called `admin.site.register()` in urls.py?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem happen upgrading from Django 1.6 -> 1.8. The solution for me turned out to be simply removing `admin.site = AdminSitePlus()` from the top of my urls.py. So, this:

```
admin.site = AdminSitePlus()
admin.autodiscover()
```

became this:

```
admin.autodiscover()
```