# Django staff user can't see any application

Tags: django, permissions, user-permissions

I have a group of user called "support". I want them to be able to log in the django admin site, view and modifiy the instances of the class "HelpContextual" of the application "support".

So I created a group "support" with the permission `support | help contextual | Can change help contextual`. The users can log in the django admin site, but they can't see any application.

I tried to give them all the permissions of the "support" application, but still, they can't see the support app. If I use a direct link to change a "help contextual" like this one : `admin/support/helpcontextual/5/change/`, I get a 403.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious... Can you point it to me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7021995/626748

I had a custom backend and removed the default django authentication backend...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have done the following steps.

1. Add group `Support.
2. Under available permissions select `support | help contextual | Can change help contextual` from `Available Permissions` and then make sure you have clicked on the arrow pointing to `Change Permissions`. This will move the specific permission to `Change Permissions`.
3. Click Save.
4. Create or open users.
5. Select `Active` and `Staff Users`.
6. Select `Support` from `Available Groups` and click the arrow pointing to `Chosen Groups`. This will move the `Support` group to `Chosen Group`.
7. Don't make any change to `User Permissions` unless you want to grant additional permissions to any specific user.
8. Click save.
9. Have the user logout and log back in.

Comment: Still got a 403 with a direct link and can't see the application in the admin if I log directly.

Comment: If you are running in dev that is running by executing command `python manage.py runserver` then right when you are trying to access the page and getting 403 error, your console should spit out messages/errors. Please post them here if you can.