# Models not visiable for stuff

Tags: django, django-admin

I've added a Model to admin page with `admin.site.register` but it's being displayed only if `superuser` logs in.

Even if i give all permissions to a stuff user the model does not show up there even though `Groups` and `Users` model does.

How do i set this right?

EDIT: maybe he needs permissions to the module? How can give those related to `user.has_module_perms` ?

Comment: what kind of a model you are trying to register? Is it a normal model or is it a proxy model?

Comment: regular model. I think i might have something to do with modul perms.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either create a group, give permissions to group and then add assign that group to user or create user and assign permissions to that user.

Add group `Stuff-users`.
Under available permissions in `Available Permissions` Select
YourApp | YourModel | Can add...
YourApp | YourModel | Can change...
YourApp | YourModel | Can Delete...

Then make sure you have clicked on the arrow pointing to Change Permissions. This will move the specific permission to Change Permissions.
Click Save.

Create or open Users. Select the user `Stuff`
Select Active and Staff Users.
Select `Stuff-users` from Available Groups and click the arrow pointing to Chosen Groups. This will move the Support group to Chosen Group.
Don't make any change to User Permissions unless you want to grant additional permissions to any specific user.
Click save.
Have the user logout and log back in.

Comment: I assigned all perms in admin panel to a stuff user and he still doesn't see that model. If i make him a superuser it's there.

Comment: Are you using a custom backend? If yes, try solution posted here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929707/django-admin-not-seeing-any-app-permission-problem/7021995#7021995

If not, then see my updated answer.